# How to keep logs in AWS if application restarts?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, logging, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I run a spring boot application in AWS with Docker. Sometimes Amazon have to restart a hardware. Then Environment Health of instance in Beanstalk goes Degraded, Warning, and restarts.

I do want my app logs from the last 7 days but it was restarted due to unforeseen AWS hardware issues so I lost my information. How can I avoid it and make AWS to save all my logs even after restart?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is true that archiving logs to S3 would work for the most part but you may want to consider installing and configuring the CloudWatch Logs agent - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/QuickStartEC2Instance.html

This will stream logs directly to CloudWatch and save them upon termination. You also could consider numerous other solutions for this such as Sumo Logic, ELK, Splunk, etc.

Comment: Thanks, BryceH

I've found it.
AWS -> CloudWatch -> Logs
/aws/elasticbeanstalk/<instancename_from_beanstalk>

Very nice!

Answer (score 0):

You should always build solutions so as to be ready even when hardware crashes. One possible solution could be that while rotating log files send them to S3 bucket. You can create a cron-job to do this.